# Getting Facebook friends list with PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm developing an app where I have to select a friend from my list, but the app is not returning my friends. Another friend who has used app appears in the list od others do not.

```
$amigos = $facebook->api('/me/friends/?fields=name,id,picture.type(normal)');
```

Why does it happen?
And what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

That is by design. In Facebook API v2.0 /me/friends only return friends that also are using the app. I would recommend reading the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends